# Visual Studio 2019 update breaks publishing (incorrect TLS version)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, publish

*Short version*:

**How to change the default TLS version of Visual Studio 2019 used to fetch dependencies?**

*Long version*:

As of Visual Studio 2019 v16.7.1 (the latest v16.7.2 doesn't fix this) I seem unable to publish any dotnet core project. The publishing operation always crashes with the following message:

```
Publish has encountered an error.
Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error.
Check the output log for more details.
```

Taking a look at the output window:
[image: error message]

As can be seen VS seems to fail trying to establish a TLS connection to nuget.
Further investigation using Wireshark for monitoring while publishing reveals this:

[image: wireshark failing]

As can be clearly seen the connection fails due to an incorrect TLS version. Visual Studio seems to use `TLSv1` which isn't supported by the nuget api. We can also see that VS is retrying a couple of times thus the large amount of packets.

Manually connecting to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json using my web browser shows that nuget.org actually uses `TLSv1.2`:

[image: wireshark success]

### So my question is: How do I tell Visual Studio to use `TLSv1.2` instead of `TLSv1` to connect to nuget.org? Or is it possible at all? Is there a Windows registry key for this?

I haven't tried reinstalling VS yet but if possible I'd like to avoid doing so.

Comment: What OS do you have? There is a chance that issue is with your operating system.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate. Didn't make any problems in the past though :|

Comment: Can you try un-checking the  ```Use TLS 1.0``` option under ```Internet Options``` -> ```Advanced``` in your OS system settings?

Comment: Un-checked it, rebooted, VS is still using TLS 1.0 :(

Comment: [make the changes to registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client#bkmk_winhttp), reboot and look if it fixes your issue

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you so much :) it was a combination of your and `imsmn`s approach that finally fixed it for me. Weird though that those TLS settings only now became a problem as publishing worked fine a few weeks ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments setting the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp\
      DefaultSecureProtocols = (DWORD): 0xAA0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp\
      DefaultSecureProtocols = (DWORD): 0xAA0
```

(more documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client#bkmk_winhttp) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi))
in combination with un-checking the `Use TLS 1.0` option under `Internet Options` -> `Advanced` in the Windows 7 control panel did the trick.